# "Manipulating" Normal Distributions

Tags: probability, matrices, statistics, normal-distribution, machine-learning

I am reading the following book https://algorithmsbook.com/optimization/files/optimization.pdf at page 281:

[image]

I am trying to understand how to manipulate the matrix terms to verify the following 2 relations:

[image]

**My Question:** Can someone please show me how to verify that 1) and 2) are true? How can I manipulate the matrix terms within the Normal Distributions (within the Gaussian Process) to verify 1) and 2)?

Thanks!

Comment: I recommend to look at the density of the bivariate normal disribution $\varphi(x,y,\rho)$ . This shows you directly what the PDF of $x|y$ is . The case above ist totally analogous.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions